# Depending on user input , targets in the build should execute

Tags: ant

I want to execute all targets in my build.xml (written using ant scripts) one by one. But these execution of targets should depend on user's input. That is,
User will be asked "if this target has to be executed (y/n)?" If users inputs "n" then that target should not get executed. Only if he gives the input as "y" then the target should executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer expanded from [ant documentation.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)

```
<project >
    <target name="ask" >
        <input
             message="All data is going to be deleted from DB continue (y/n)?"
                  validargs="y,n"
                  addproperty="do.delete"
              />
                  <condition property="do.abort">
                        <equals arg1="n" arg2="${do.delete}"/>
          </condition>
        <fail if="do.abort">Build aborted by user.</fail>
        <echo message="Dropping database"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Please do see [What are the best resources to learn Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367714/what-are-the-best-resources-to-learn-ant). It has a sample build.xml with some fairly useful targets...